# Change the rsp manually using assembly method to work with an allocated stack

Tags: assembly, x86-64

I am trying to move from the thread stack to a stack allocated on heap. I implemented a simple assembly function that updates the `rsp`, but when calling a function after changing the stack address, the local variable address is not the new stack address (but, it's in the heap memory address range). I guess the issue is somewhere with my understanding of the calling convention, the code and the output is attached:

file: **switch_stack.S:**

```
.p2align 4, ,15
.global switch_stack
switch_stack:
    movq    0(%rsp), %rdx /*Save ret adr in rdx*/ 
    movq    %rdi, %rsp /* rsp points to the new stack address*/
    movq    %rdx, 0(%rsp) /*Save ret adr in new stack head*/
    ret
```

file: **switch_stack.h:**

```cpp
extern "C" void
switch_stack(uint64_t pNewStackAddress);
```

file: **main.cc:**

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cstdint>
#include <switch_stack.h>

void
func()
{
    uint64_t funcLocalVar = 3;
    printf("func() local var address: %p\n", &funcLocalVar);
}

int32_t
main()
{
    uint64_t mainLocalVar = 2;
    printf("main() local var address: %p\n", &mainLocalVar);

    uint64_t stackSizeByte = 8192;
    void* pNewStack = malloc(stackSizeByte);
    void* pNewStackHighAddress =
      (static_cast<char*>(pNewStack) + stackSizeByte - 1);
    printf("Stack bottom address is: %p\n", pNewStack);
    printf("Stack upper address is: %p\n", pNewStackHighAddress);

    switch_stack(reinterpret_cast<uint64_t>(pNewStackHighAddress));

    func();
    //rest of the code...

    return 0;
}
```

**compilation and output** (windows machine)

```
PS $> g++ -std=c++20 main.cc switch_stack.S -o main.exe
PS $> ./main.exe
main() local var address: 00000067553FFA80
 Stack bottom address is: 00000239B2D8D170
  Stack upper address is: 00000239B2D8F16F
func() local var address: 00000239B2D834B8
```

Would appreciate any help and explanation.

Comment: @273K: It is also not C++, using only C lib functions. All the code looks... special. BTW: What is the intention to exchange the stack? Is it only for academic purpose?

Comment: You've set the stack pointer to an odd address.  Not sure what the processor is going to do with that.  You want to set rsp to malloc'memory + (8192/8-1)*8.  The -1 should apply to 64-bit words, not bytes.

Comment: If you want to understand more, then disassemble the C functions to see what the compiler is doing under the hood.  And use the debugger to single step in assembly/machine code.

Comment: For a context-switch function to look like a normal function call that *eventually* returns (from the caller's PoV), the usual technique is to `push` the call-preserved registers (RBX, RBP, R12-R15) on the old stack and pop them from the new stack.

Comment: Oh wait, you're trying to return to the caller with RSP different, and seeing what happens afterwards, i.e. how things break?  Presumably you compiled without optimization;  `-fno-omit-frame-pointer`  is the default at `-O0`, so local variables will be addressed relative to RBP, which the prologue set up as a frame pointer.  Look at the compiler generated asm for `main`, e.g. as you single-step through the asm in a debugger.  If you compile with `-O1` or higher, you'll probably get an address pointing into the new stack, as long as the calling function doesn't use a VLA or `alloca`.

Comment: BTW, if you used `push`/`ret`, you wouldn't need the caller to offset by 1; you could pass an address that's one past the end of the buffer.  Of course, you'd then return to the caller with RSP pointing past the end of the allocation, so that parent function's `ret` might segfault if it's in a separate page.

Comment: **The Windows x64 calling convention passes the first arg in RCX**.  Your asm expects it in RDI, where non-Windows systems would pass it (the x86-64 System V calling convention.)  So maybe something leaves a value near `00000239B2D834B8` in RDI, and that's what you're actually setting RSP to?  It's a call-preserved register in Windows x64 so `malloc` couldn't leave it there.  But anyway, I think you're asking why `func() local var address` is outside the high/low range of your allocation?  There were so many other showstopper problems in this code I didn't notice that right away.

Comment: It's weird that you'd try to set RSP to a misaligned address (`...F` if you'd gotten the calling convention correct.)  Either set it to a whole qword lower, or to the qword past the end, like I said so you can `push`/`ret`.  Or no, since Windows x64 has shadow space, you'd return to the middle of `main` where its prologue has already allocated shadow space for the call to `func`, that shadow space would be past the end of the `malloc`ed region.  Anyway, probably something like `(char*)pNewStack + 8192 - 64` or something to leave some margin.